# How to manually download Kubernetes Busybox image?

Tags: kubernetes, busybox

My proxy settings (controlled by admin) doesn't allow me to pull busybox image. I want to test a few things on busybox. How can I manually download busybox image, so that I can push and use it?

Or is there an alternative to busybox that I can download manually. I just want to run simple hello world program.

EDIT: I know obvious solution is to reach out to admin which I already did and they declined my request so I just need an image with the shell which I can download outside the network and push on kubernetes instance.

Comment: Talk to your admin? I think this question is missing details, like how Kubernetes is configured (what CRI, what security policies, can you run a registry, etc). And it's also not a programming question so it belongs better on another SE site (ServerFault, SuperUser, or DevOps).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually push the image from your local machine to k8s nodes. This assumes that you've the SSH access to the nodes. Following are the steps

- On your local machine, download the image.
- Convert the image into tar file using `docker save <image-name> <image-name.tar>`
- Push the image to remote server using `scp <image-name.tar> username@host:/path/to/remote/server/directory`
- Finally, SSH into the machine & load the image with `docker load -i /path/to/remote/server/directory/image-name.tar`

Comment: I know I can push the local image but I am not finding any way/url  to download the image.  Everywhere it is shown to do so using docker command. For that I will need to install and register docker on local machine.